# Class operators can not access member variables

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, member-variables

I am working on an integer class that should be able to do basic arithmetic. The integer values are stored in an array where every array element holds two integer values. I convert this array of integers into the member variable integer.

```
class Integer {
private:
  char* arr;
  bool t;
  int integer;
  int arr_len;

public:
...
Integer operator-();
Integer operator+(Integer& i);
...
};
```

The first operator is supposed to just negate the integer value. However, VS tells me that I do not have enough operator parameters. Further, I can not access the member variables in both operators and the stand alone integer is not defined.

```
Integer& operator-()
{
  Integer temp;
  temp.integer = -integer;;
  return temp;
}

Integer& operator+(Integer& i)
{
  Integer temp;
  temp.integer = integer + i.integer;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: You need to tell the compiler which class you wish the operator to belong to. Do that by adding a scope to the function's implementation `Integer::operator-()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indicate that the operators belong to the class `Integer`.

To do so, add `Integer::` before names of each operator.

Also the signature in the definitions of operator doesn't match to the declarations. They return `Integer` in the declarations, but they are defined to return `Integer&`.

```
Integer Integer::operator-()
{
  Integer temp;
  temp.integer = -integer;
  return temp;
}

Integer Integer::operator+(Integer& i)
{
  Integer temp;
  temp.integer = integer + i.integer;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix the dangling references too ;-)

Comment: Thank you. But now VS tells me that the declaration is not compatible.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @rafix07 Why? The operators are (unary) `-` and `+`, not `-=` and `+=`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Could you explain why I would want to use a reference for operator overloading, or provide a link to a smiliar question already asked ?